# How to draw a line that tapers at the end in canvas js?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I know how to draw lines normally in canvas js.

```
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100, 5);
ctx.stroke();
```

However, how do I draw a line with pointed or smoothly tapering edges?

Is there a simple way or do I use arcs instead?

Expected output:

[image: Tapered line]

Comment: That's quite unclear what you expect. What would stroking a closed rectangle look like for instance? To do exactly what you shown, bezier curves would be the best tool.

Comment: The output I expect is exactly like the image I have posted. I will try bezier curves, but I think arcs would be an easier solution.